# jQuery nestedsortable disable/enable

Tags: jquery, nested-sortable

I'm using jQuery nestedsortable plugin for sorting ul list. But sometimes i need to disable and enable it. It was easy with ui sortable, but can't find way to do it with nested list.

I tried to use:

```
$("ul").unbind(".nestedSortable");
```

But then no way to enable it again. Thanks for help.

**UPDATE:** 
Analyzing plugin source code helps.

```
$(".tree ul").nestedSortable('destroy');
```

will fully destroy nested sortable instance.